# Mobile menu dropdown not recognized when site is hosted

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

*EDIT: The menu somehow seems to work intermittently. My phone is displaying everything perfectly, while Chrome has gone back and forth over the past few minutes (without me editing anything.)*

*EDIT 2: I realized that in Chrome it works when I add the www to the start of the URL but doesn't work when the www is omitted. So, youbrewyou.co doesn't work, but www.youbrewyou.co does work. Anyone have experience with this?*

My site works fine locally, and the jsfiddle below essentially works. When I host the files though the mobile menu falls apart. See how at http://www.youbrewyou.co

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L2tuuguu/5/

HTML

```
<div class="mobileNavbar container-fluid px-1 float-xs-right hidden-md-up">
    <div id="toggle">
      <div class="one"></div>
      <div class="two"></div>
      <div class="three"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#toggle {
  width: 28px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#toggle div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: rgba(38,50,56,1);
  margin: 4px auto;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#toggle.on .one {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
}

#toggle.on .two {
  opacity: 0;
}

#toggle.on .three {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -8px);
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing. Please and thank you for any advice!

Comment: It works fine for me with and without the www. Have you changed any local IP settings (hosts file maybe)? Also, the homeHero2.jpg badly needs optimising (currently 916KB - about 90% of your page!).

Comment: what do you mean it "falls apart"?

Comment: Thanks Tims, will optimize. This whole process has been very trial and error for me.

Comment: Punit, the screenshots demonstrated how the menu fell apart. I've fixed it now though. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine on this end. MacOS, Safari, Chrome, FF. I suggest trying to clear your browsers or websites cache.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It just sorted itself out after a few hours. Looks like you were right.

Comment: Nice :) In addition there are methods, one being in Cpanel where you can control the cache to refresh more quickly, so a visitor does not encounter the same problem if changes were made.